# Class Diagram if the relationships are correct

Tags: c#, design-patterns, class-diagram

I created a Class Diagram. This is just a concept but i want to know if the relationship are correct and if i fully understand it.

MainClass

- CreateClassA(); creates ClassA with new ClassA();
- CreateClassB(); creates ClassB with new ClassB();
- getConcreteFromCreator(); get the concrete class from creator. The creator has a switch case to determine which concrete class to return.

  - After the class is returned then call it for example (Abstract callConcrete = new ConreateA())
- CreateClassAA(); creates ClassAA with Interface createClassAA = new ClassAA();

ClassAA

- ClassAA creates classBB with new ClassBB();

Relationship from ClassAA to ClassBB is this suppose to be a composition? since the classAA is the creator of ClassBB and it depends on it from existing
The relation between InterfaceAA and ClassAA is realization. I wasn't able to draw the line using NClass diagram.

[Class Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTvGe.png)

Comment: I can't figure the relation between what you explain and what I see on the diagram. For example, every `CreateX` and `getThat` method on the diagram returns `void`. Do they store the created instances inside? What does it mean "call it... (Abstract callConcrete = new ConreateA())"? What is "creates ClassAA with Interface"?

Comment: What i meant is to create the ConcreateA class inside a method in MainClass. Once it's created then i can invoke the methods in ConcreateA class from MainClass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Relation between `ClassAA` and `ClassBB` is composition only in case the instance of `ClassBB` created by `ClassAA` is stored inside `ClassAA` and not shared with external entities. In this case it would be good OO practice to hide this implementation detail and perform the necessary initialization inside the `ClassAA`'s constructor or a dedicated `Initialize` method.
2. Don't know anything about NClass, but realization is specified by a dashed line with a hollow triangle pointing to interface. Based on the screenshots on their site, it is supported.

Comment: Thanks! The NClass doesn't allow me to create the realization line between InterfaceAA and ClassAA. It's giving me an error "Cannot create relationship between the two objects."

Comment: The cause could be that there is a special type of drawing for interfaces, it probably looks different from class and is not rectangle but a circle.